# MVC Best way to get values in controller of dynamically Textboxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor

I want to create a Poll view where the users can enter the name of the poll and the options. But at the beginning I don't know how many options the users will enter.

I'm thinking about having a textbox and a button to create another textbox.

My problem is that I don't know how to get the value of this new textbox.

What is the best way?

I thought of creating an `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PollOptionsStr)` with all values separated by comma and populating it with jQuery, but I don't know if this is the best option.

Comment: You can read id of the first text box and create a new id as `old_textboxid_1, old_textboxid_2` and so on. And then you can create a new textbox with the new id and append it to DOM.

Comment: Definitely not a hidden input :) You just need to give your dynamically created inputs the correct name attribute that matches your model. What is your model?

Comment: Add your code for better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your model is

```
public class PollModel
{
    public string PollName{get;set;}
    public List<string> PollOptions{get;set;}
    public int MaxPollStars{get;set;}
}
```

Then your post method will expect a PollModel

```
[httpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DynamicPoll(PollModel model)
{
   foreach(var item in model.PollOptions)
   {
      ///do something to each poll option
   }
}
```

you can map the dynamicly created poll options using JS to create an element that has structure

```
name="PollOptions"
```

Comment: If its only `List<string>` then all it needs to be is `name="PollOptions"` (indexers only required when its a collection of complex properties :). And you cannot use a `foreach` to generate existing options (it does not create the correct `name` attributes for binding)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have edited the my answer.